# Regexp to select images with whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex

Im tried several combinations but it seams to end up by inserting every possible sign.

I have a regexp that looks like

```
<img[^>]*?src=["']([\w:\\\/\s\S]*[.a-zA-Z]{3,})[^>]*?>
```

I want to select the src part from an image.

Sample URL looks like

```
Sample <img alt="foo" src="c:\my-folder\contains.dot\and space\in myImagePath.png" title="bar" >
```

but this selects title as well, I want to stop at the src's end `"` .

I also tried some more constelations but with same or no result....

Is there a was to stop at `"` when first `"` was mached ?

**ORIGINAL DATA**

***Original HTMLCode copied from VS2017 console***:

```
<style>*{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}</style><p><img src=\"C:\\Users\\JustMe\\Desktop\\de mo1.png\" width=\"1635\" height=\"989\" /></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

***Code I used originaly***:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public List<string[]> FetchLinksFromSource(string htmlSource)
    {
        List<string[]> links = new List<string[]>();

        int i = 1;
        string regexImgSrc = @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
        MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(htmlSource, regexImgSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
        {
            string[] matches = new string[3];
            string href = m.Groups[1].Value;
            matches[0] = href;
            matches[1] = new Uri(href).ToString();
            matches[2] = "imageID_" + i++.ToString();
            links.Add(matches);
        }
        return links;
    }
```

This code crashes if image or path has white spaces!

Comment: FYI: `[\w:\\\/\s\S]*` == `[\s\S]*` == *everything*

Comment: Easier to use [^\"]+ : string input = "<img alt=\"foo\" src=\"c:\\my-folder\\contains.dot\\and space\\in myImagePath.png\" title=\"bar\" >";
            string pattern = "alt=\"(?'alt'[^\"]+)\"\\s+src=\"(?'src'[^\"]+)\"\\s+title=\"(?'title'[^\"]+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern);

            Console.WriteLine("alt = '{0}', src = '{1}', title = '{2}'", 
                match.Groups["alt"].Value,
                match.Groups["src"].Value,
                match.Groups["title"].Value);

            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Are you sure using regex patterns that answered in this page!? none of them crash with spaces! @Dwza

Comment: Currently i use the one in my original code sample. This cuts the string at space. All other strings doesnt seem to find the image part. may i just include them wrong.... dont know if i have to escape " with " that it looks like ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
<img[^>]*?src=["']([^"']*[.a-zA-Z]{3,})[^>]*?>
                   ^^^^^
```

See it [live](https://regex101.com/r/8a0aRA/1)

Comment: cant get it run in c# :/

Comment: @Dwza `new Uri(href).ToString()` this can't work if your `href` contains spaces

Comment: ok, not bad... i could change this later... but first of all i need the regex to work so it matches the imagepath with white spaces

Comment: @Dwza The code you provided doesn't not include *my* regex

Comment: i know... because it doent work. at least not when i use it in c#. do i have to replace " with "" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139393/discussion-between-thomas-ayoub-and-dwza).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use `\1` for end of `src=` with the same " or ' in the beginning:

```
<img[^>]*?src=("|')(.*?)\1[^>]*?>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K1u39s/2)

Comment: but this doesnt match right. It goes accross the " see your demo :)

Comment: in Demo link or pasted pattern in answer? in demo link i used `(.*?)` but in pasted pattern in answer, `(.*)`. Answer updated now.

Comment: it still matches the whole img tag and not only the image link

Comment: matching and capturing are two different things. src is in 2nd captured group. @Dwza

Comment: ah, i saw the type was javascript... i changed it and it works as expacted